# How to access text file in windows/unix directory through hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to copy log files from the windows/unix environment to HDFS in a specific directory structure. I know that I can do copyFromLocal in the hadoop shell but is it possible to do through a java code using Mapper.

Comment: Why would you use Mapper to do the stuff? Can't you script it to do copyFromLocal?

Comment: I dont want to use any shell script..just pure Java code.

Comment: Yeah script it and call from java?

Comment: Why must be in the Mapper? I think it should be called in the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean copying a local file(or a directory) from local machine to HDFS, here is the code:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path localPath = new Path("your_local_path");
    Path remotePath = new Path("your_hdfs_path");
    fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath, remotePath);
```

Comment: Thanks ..Please can you tell me that what do you mean by that it should be called in the driver ?

Comment: Because the mapper can run in any node in the cluster, the `local` of mapper is not deterministic. The driver will run in your local machine. So you should call `copyFromLocalFile` in it.